# Display a list on the front end from wp_remote_get()

Tags: api, json, wp-remote-get

I am getting the data I need from the request but I am not getting to the bottom of how to loop over the data and create a list on the front end. I presumed it would be a `foreach` loop but I am just not getting close to displaying the data.

The API is - https://www.football-data.org/

Code I have been using is below.

```
function cw_get_next_three_matches() {

  $request = 'https://api.football-data.org/v4/competitions/PL/matches';
  $args = array(
    'method' => 'GET',
    'headers' => array(
      'X-Auth-Token' => '8a43decf90b64945a5cfc004fa291b8c'
    )
  );

  $response = wp_remote_get($request, $args);

 if ( is_wp_error( $response ) ) {
    $error_message = $response->get_error_message();
    return "Something went wrong: $error_message";
 }

  $results = json_decode(wp_remote_retrieve_body( $response ), true);

  // var_dump($results);
  $html = '<ul>';
  foreach( $results as $result ) {
    $html .= '<li>' . $result->id . '</li>';
  }
  $html = '</ul>';
  return $html;
}
```

Comment: Use `json_decode` and dump the result which you can then manipulate as you wish. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: Do you have a piece of code that you have written so that I can trigger and display the output using JSON

Comment: @Maqk Sorry, I have updated the question to include the code I'm using. It should be useable as a shortcode to embed on different pages. I just get error after error when trying to access data from the JSON.